# Why is $ the default symbol for a user shell and # the default symbol for a root shell?

Tags: shell, prompt, history

Operating a standard bash shell on a server, the PS1 prompt defaults to ending in a $ for non-root users, and # for root.

IE:

```
ubuntu@server:~$ sudo su
root@server:/home/ubuntu#
```

Why is this?

Comment: Historically or more directly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Historically the original /bin/sh Bourne shell would use `$` as the normal prompt and `#` for the root user prompt (and csh would use `%`).  This made it pretty easy to tell if you were running as superuser or not.

`#` is also the comment character, so anyone blindly re-entering data wouldn't run any real commands.

More modern shells (eg ksh, bash) continue this distinction of `$` and `#` although it's less important when you can set more complicated values such as the username, hostname, directory :-)

Comment: Can you give an example of how `#` being the comment character prevents someone running real commands if they're blindly re-entering data?

Comment: What happens if you cut'n'paste the complete line `# reboot` - answer... nothing, 'cos the `#` is a comment.

Comment: I had a user client who configured his prompt like `john->`. He used to complain that all my scripts stopped working after two or three days. That would be because he kept pasting `> myScript` onto his command line.

Comment: I had something similar a few days ago.  I asked a client to "copy and paste the log into the issue".  They copied a log, pasted it into bash, and sent me the output.  Every second line was: `bash: ...: command not found`

Answer (score 13):

Tradition.

[The POSIX standard says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_05_03) (my emphasis):

> PS1
>
> This variable is used for interactive prompts. Historically, the
> "superuser" has had a prompt of `#`. Since privileges are not required
> to be monolithic, it is difficult to define which privileges should
> cause the alternate prompt. **However, a sufficiently powerful user
> should be reminded of that power by having an alternate prompt.**

See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/57613/452045) to virtually the same question on the SuperUser forum.