# User Mode Symbol for Bash Prompts

Tags: shell, prompt

I am trying to find the names/differences/what is the symbol called at the of the prompt provided at the entry line for Bash.

For example: user@user~$ what is the $ called, and why on some systems is user % not $? is that a setting that can be changed?

I am thinking about this from the perception of Cisco IOS, between > (user) to # privileged exec. The symbols serve a purpose there, so what purpose do they serve on a *Nix system?

Comment: Cisco IOS is a *Nix system for that matter :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the character has a name; it's traditionally used to indicate whether you're `root` or not (`#` means you're root, `$` or `%` means you're not). `$` is used in Bourne-style shells (including Bash), `%` is used in the C shell and Zsh. In Zsh the definition is slightly wider: `#` is displayed if you're `root` or if you have raised POSIX capabilities.

Your prompt definition determines whether this appears: [in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt), `\$` in a prompt definition is replaced by `#` or `$`, [in Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html), `%#` is replaced by `#` or `%`. You can use other characters in Zsh by using the expanded version, `%(!.#.%%)`.

[Why is $ the default symbol for a user shell and # the default symbol for a root shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/291729/86440) has more info.

Comment: at least on Debian, `tcsh` seems to show `>` for a normal user and `#` for root, which matches the Cisco convention.

Comment: @ilkkachu It does that if you start it as `tcsh`; if you start it as `csh` it uses `%` and `#`. The characters can be customised using the `promptchars` variable.

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash`:

> PROMPTING
>          When executing interactively, bash displays the primary prompt PS1 when it is ready to read a command, and the secondary prompt PS2
>   when it needs more input
>          to  complete a command.  Bash allows these prompt strings to be customized by inserting a number of backslash-escaped special
>   characters that are decoded as
>          follows:
>
> ...
>
> - \$     if the effective UID is 0, a #, otherwise a $

So, it is hard-coded in the `bash`*. The same probably applies to other shells. I recall that on very old unices from 80'es it used to be `%`. Nowadays `csh` uses `%`

---

* You could of course customize the PS1, but without this builtin feature to use one or another char based on UID